# is there a way to dynamically change the value and display of a select tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my Javascript inside of my html file:

```
<script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#sub").click(function(){
                            var user_issue = $("#issue").val();
                            var user_priority = $("#priority").val();
                            var user_type = $("#type1").val();
                            $.post("BugReport.php",{issue:user_issue,priority:user_priority,type1:user_type},function(data){
                                $("#result").html(data);
                                //location.reload(true);
                            });
                            $.post('BugDisplay.php',{},function(data){
                                $("#BugDisplay").html(data);
                            });
                            document.getElementById('issue').value='';
                            document.getElementById('type1').value='Listing Discrepancy';  //this is my attempt at solving the problem.
                        });
                        $.post('BugDisplay.php',{},function(data){
                                $("#BugDisplay").html(data);
                            });
                    });
                </script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<select name = "type1" id = "type1">
                <option value = "Listing Discrepancy">Listing Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "PO Discrepancy">PO Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "Pricing Discrepancy">Pricing Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "Program Glitch">Program Glitch</option>
                <option value = "Receiving Discrepancy">Receiving Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "RMA Discrepancy">RMA Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "Sales Discrepancy">Sales Discrepancy</option>
                <option value = "Shipping Discrepancy">Shipping Discrepancy</option>
            </select>
```

What i want to do is on a click change the select statement so that it resets back to the default display of "Listing Discrepency" and also assign the value to "Listing Discrepency".

Comment: Do not judge him because he asks basic questions. Everybody is a beginner in the beginning. :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change the `selectedIndex` property of the select to the first `0` item.

HTML:

```
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".reset").click(function () {
    $('#type1').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

Or just pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("type1").selectedIndex = "0";
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wazaaaap/pvjk6jrx/).

Comment: In this case, how is it different than document.getElementById('type1').value='Listing Discrepancy';?

Comment: You don't need to write `Listing Discrepancy` (the exact value)

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly.  I had already created the button though.

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved with

```
$("#type1").val('Listing Discrepancy');
```

in your `onclick` event callback

**[example](http://jsfiddle.net/vnhn0z2u/1/)**

Comment: How is it different than `document.getElementById('type1').value='Listing Discrepancy';`?

Comment: Ahh yes, i missed that, It works ok though, see example

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code after select tag**

```
<button onClick="$('#type1').val('Listing Discrepancy');">Reset</button>
```